# Flash as3 show specific movie clip on click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I just started using flash so this might be a simple thing so please be patient.

I'm doing a project were I have a map and you can click the places on the map and the info appears. I could manage to link every button_btn to every info_mc but that would take forever, so I tried to make a function that would read the buttons name and redirect to the info_mc itself. However since the name is being converted to string when I change from name_mc to name_info it is not redirecting. Here is the code.

```
    winterfell_info.visible = false;

    map.winterfell_btn.doubleclickEnabled = true;
    map.winterfell_btn.mouseChildren = doubleClickEnabled;
    map.winterfell_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, show_clicked);

    function show_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
         var get_name = e.currentTarget.name;
         var open_info_string = get_name.slice(0,-3) + "info";
         //I've tried some things here but nothing is working for me. 
         var open_info = stage.getChildByName(open_info_string);
         open_info.visible = true;      
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

And if you wondering yes its a map for Game of Thrones.

Comment: Are you sure the stage is the parent of `open_info_string`? Because `getChildByName()` isn't recursive. And are you certain you gave it the name "winterfell_info" when you created it? Because setting the `.name` property is not the same as naming the variable referencing the mc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes around "open_info_string", as a first measure, and change the capital S in that string to normal one "s", because Actionscript is case sensitive.

```
var open_info = stage.getChildByName(open_info_string);
```

Then, if it wouldn't work at once, insert a `trace(open_info_string);` before you try to reach the movie clip, to find out whether it was cropped correctly.

Comment: Thank you, but still didn't work, "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference". And trace() gives me winterfell_info which is exactly what I want

Comment: Look, I see you have changed the question a bit. Now. You are now having your "open_info_string" variable set to something useful, say "help_info", but you are searching for a movie clip named "open_info_string"! You need to understand what is a variable and what is not. If you write `stage.getChildByName(open_info_string);` you are asking for an object whose name is contained in that variable WHICH is named "open_info_string", but when you write `stage.getChildByName("open_info_string");` you are asking for an object which name equals "open_info_string" and this is a constant.

Comment: I understand now and I fixed it, thank you. But still it doenst work.

Comment: for the great justice, insert `trace(winterfell_info.name);`, you might be greatly surprised. But, if you need to reference a variable with such a name, use another syntax: `var open_info = this[open_info_string];` and trace if it's null. For this, you shuold have it declared in your class, with `public var winterfell_info:MovieClip;` If this works, you're golden.

Comment: Oh man, you are great
var open_info = this[open_info_string];
that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i've done something similar.. i don't have time to adapt the code, but if you look at what I did here I believe it'll help you. I'm making an array with the instance names of objects on my video player and then created a function which adds the appropriate event listener using a switch case statement.. easiest way to do this in mass, in my opinion.

```
var buttons:Array = [clicky,pauseBtn,playBtn];

for (var i in buttons)
{
    buttons[i].buttonMode = buttons[i].useHandCursor = true;
    addEventListner(buttons[i]);
}

function addEventListner(movieClip)
{
    movieClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    switch (movieClip.name)
    {
    case "playBtn" :
    youTubeHolder.videoPlayer.playVideo();
    videoController.playBtn.visible = false;
    videoController.pauseBtn.visible = true;
    break;

    case "pauseBtn" :
    youTubeHolder.videoPlayer.pauseVideo();
    videoController.playBtn.visible = true;
    videoController.pauseBtn.visible = false;
    break;

    case "stopBtn" :
    youTubeHolder.videoPlayer.seekTo(0);
    youTubeHolder.videoPlayer.stopVideo();

    break;

    default :
    trace(movieClip.name+"is not a valid button");
    }


    });
}
```